# Localhost inside docker - neo4j

Tags: docker, neo4j, containers

I'm trying to create a dockerfile which sets up a neo4j instance. Currently I have the following:

```
FROM neo4j:3.0
MAINTAINER Andy

CMD curl \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-X POST -d '{"password":"mypassword"}' \
-u neo4j:neo4j http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j/password
```

From here, I then build the image and run using the following command

```
docker run -p 7474:7474 myimage
```

While I'm able to access the neo4j panel at `localhost:4747` on my host machine, the curl command which is intended to be run inside the container, is unable to access it's own localhost instance.

So I guess my question is, am I doing this correctly and how does one call localhost from inside a container?

*Just to clarify, I don't want the curl request to escape the container - it should communicate with neo4j from inside the container.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to use the environment variable `$NEO4J_AUTH`that controls authentication as explained [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/docker-3.x/).

For example this disable authentication

```
docker run -p 7474:7474 -e NEO4J_AUTH=none -d neo4j:3.0
```

You might also want to check the [entrypoint script](https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j-publish/blob/860588baa6a9e97c7d10bdbc0084e4c59f3886a6/3.0.3-community/docker-entrypoint.sh) of the docker `neo4j:3.0` image, so you can make your own version if the options given are not enough for you.

Comment: Thanks, that turned out to be the solution and I learned about dockerfiles on the way

Answer (score 2):

Your container is *only* running curl; based on your Dockerfile above, you are not starting neo4j inside the container so of course it's not available on `localhost`.

If you're running it in another container, you would need to use the ip address of that container.

Comment: Based on this, are you saying that CMD will override the source image CMD? I assumed the order was like this `source-run, source-cmd -> my-run, my-cmd`

Comment: A docker image can only have a single `CMD`.  If you specify `CMD` in your dockerfile, you override anything that existed in the base image.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: even if you use the `RUN` directive which was intended for something like that, it would fail because at the buildtime of your image the neo4j is not running. BTW accept the answer it ist good ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, my approach to setting the password was rather long winded. After looking at the Dockerfile for the neo4j image, I found that setting the password only required me to change the environment variable of *NEO4J_AUTH* like so:

```
FROM neo4j:3.0
MAINTAINER Andy

ENV NEO4J_AUTH neo4j/password
```